# How to force a text to fit inside a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div with `width: 200px` and I am adding text in it dynamically, I want the text to fit in this div but the text is getting out. I have tried to change the font size on character count but it does not work in all cases, like if string contains character with more width like **W** or **M**, the text goes out of the div.
Below is my code

```
if(cs >= 1 && cs <= 4) {
 if(this.engravingFontCaseSenstiveOptions(cText) == "Lower")
    {
        $('#overlay_image_text').css({'margin-top':'-162px'});
        $('#overlay_image_text').css({'font-size':60+'px'});
    }else if(this.engravingFontCaseSenstiveOptions(cText) == "Upper")
    {
        $('#overlay_image_text').css({'margin-top':'-154px'});
        $('#overlay_image_text').css({'font-size':48+'px'});
        $('#overlay_image_text').css({'margin-left':'0px'});
    }else
    {
        $('#overlay_image_text').css({'margin-top':'-162px'});
        $('#overlay_image_text').css({'font-size':60+'px'});
        $('#overlay_image_text').css({'margin-left':'0px'});
    }
 }
 else if(cs == 5) {
   if(this.engravingFontCaseSenstiveOptions(cText) == "Lower")
    {
        $('#overlay_image_text').css({'margin-top':'-152px'});
        $('#overlay_image_text').css({'font-size':54+'px'});
        $('#overlay_image_text').css({'margin-left':'0px'});
    }else if(this.engravingFontCaseSenstiveOptions(cText) == "Upper")
    {
        $('#overlay_image_text').css({'margin-top':'-143px'});
        $('#overlay_image_text').css({'font-size':45+'px'});
        $('#overlay_image_text').css({'margin-left':'0px'});
    }else
    {
        $('#overlay_image_text').css({'margin-top':'-143px'});
        $('#overlay_image_text').css({'font-size':45+'px'});
        $('#overlay_image_text').css({'margin-left':'0px'});
    }
}
```

Comment: Why `45+'px'` and not `'45px'` ?

Comment: no special reason, it works both ways

Comment: Your last `else if` should be removed as it does what `else` does

Comment: No it is the default check for `Mixed` case sensitivity of characters

Comment: I'm sorry that everyone is commenting your code without giving an answer to your question! If you have one single line you can try playing with line height. I guess that you dont want the text to spread on multiple lines? You could also prevent any text formatting at all with <pre> tag. Or you couold always use a font that will have one size for all letters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do like this, where you measure the text size

*Made a minor update where the min font size is passed as a param*

```js
function getStyle(elem,prop) {
  return window.getComputedStyle(elem,null).getPropertyValue(prop);
}
function setFontSize(elem,minsize) {
  var tst = document.createElement('div');
  tst.textContent = elem.textContent;
  tst.style = 'position:absolute;left:-9999px;display:inline-block;';
  document.body.appendChild(tst);
  tst.style.fontSize = minsize + 'px';
  tst.style.fontWeight = getStyle(elem,'font-weight');
  tst.style.fontFamily = getStyle(elem,'font-family').split(',')[0];
  while (minsize < 1000) {      
    if (parseInt(getStyle(tst,'width')) > 200) {
      elem.style.fontSize = (minsize - 2) + 'px';
      break;
    }
    tst.style.fontSize = minsize++ + 'px';
  }
  document.body.removeChild(tst);
}

setFontSize(document.querySelector('.sizedtext'),5);
```

```css
.sizedtext {
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-family: Arial;
}
```

```html
<div class="sizedtext">WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW</div>
```

Comment: that's what I needed, but as I mentioned, I am entering the text dynamically, can you please update your answer if number of character decreses, it should get back to previous font size?

Comment: @baig772 Made a minor update, where the original size is stored in a variable and reused. This can of course be optimized in many ways so look at this as a concept more than a final solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can toggle the below class:

```
.myFitClass {
    overflow: inherit;
    text-overflow: inherit;
    white-space: normal;
    text-align: justify;
}
```

It would be:

```
$(element).addClass('myFitClass');
//         ^^^ -> also `removeClass` or even `toggleClass`
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes but what would be the `CSS` in that class to fit the font?

Comment: @baig772. All them ;)

Comment: It's a good idea to demonstrate your solution either using [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or with a StackSnippet (press Ctrl+M and create your demo)

Answer (score 0):

You can optimize your code even more, you repeat a lot of syntax and do your code slower.

```
if (cs >= 1 && cs <= 4)
{
    if(this.engravingFontCaseSenstiveOptions(cText) == "Lower")
    {
        $('#overlay_image_text').css({
            'margin-top' : '-162px',
            'font-size' : '60px'
        });
    }
    else if(this.engravingFontCaseSenstiveOptions(cText) == "Upper")
    {
        $('#overlay_image_text').css({
            'margin-top' : '-154px',
            'margin-top' : '-154px',
            'font-size' : '48px',
            'margin-left' : '0px'
        });
    }
    else
    {
        $('#overlay_image_text').css({
            'margin-top' : '-162px',
            'font-size' : '60px',
            'margin-left' : '0px'
        });
    }
}
else if(cs == 5)
{
    if(this.engravingFontCaseSenstiveOptions(cText) == "Lower")
    {
        $('#overlay_image_text').css({
            'margin-top' : '-152px',
            'font-size' : '54px',
            'margin-left' : '0px'
        });
    }
    else if(this.engravingFontCaseSenstiveOptions(cText) == "Upper")
    {
        $('#overlay_image_text').css({
            'margin-top' : '-143px',
            'font-size' : '45px',
            'margin-left' : '0px'
        });
    }
    else
    {
        $('#overlay_image_text').css({
            'margin-top' : '-143px',
            'font-size' : '45px',
            'margin-left' : '0px'
        });
    }
}
```

Now just so your text does not leave the container div #overlay_image_text added to the word-wrap

```
#overlay_image_text {
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

You can see more in https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/word-wrap http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-wrap.asp

Answer (score 0):

just I want to suggest an example about fit text inside fixed `<div>`:

***HTML:***

```
<div id="fitText">

</div>
```

***CSS:***

```
#fitText {
height:250px; /* height can be anything */
width:280px; /* width can be anything */
font-size:40px; /* start off big and it will scale down */
background:lightblue;
border:solid 2px blue;
font-family: Arial;
}
```

***JS:***

```
var autoSizeText;

autoSizeText = function() {
var el, elements, _i, _len, _results;
elements = $('#fitText');
if (elements.length < 0) {
    return;
}
_results = [];
for (_i = 0, _len = elements.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
el = elements[_i];
_results.push((function(el) {
  var resizeText, _results1;
  resizeText = function() {
    var elNewFontSize;
    elNewFontSize = (parseInt($(el).css('font-size').slice(0, -2)) - 1) + 'px';
    return $(el).css('font-size', elNewFontSize);
  };
  _results1 = [];
  while (el.scrollHeight > el.offsetHeight) {
    _results1.push(resizeText());
  }
   return _results1;
})(el));
}
return _results;
};

return autoSizeText();
```

[JsFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Shady_Alset/9x2vdkc7/)

*I hope it helps, thanks !*

Comment: exactly that's what I needed, let me do my work around and will get back to you. Thanks :)

Comment: have a look at this fiddle, It is not working in this case
http://jsfiddle.net/9x2vdkc7/2/

Comment: @baig772 Have a look at my answer, it fixes that text ... and is also easy to follow ... maybe easier to convert that to jQuery if you don't want vanilla js script

Comment: @baig772 Just Add this line `word-wrap: break-word;` to CSS, and also you should fix div height when you use break-word to prevent div from expanding down, [your updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Shady_Alset/8xums4zo/1/)